# ngAfterViewInit clicks only first button in array. Activates result of other subsequent array ElementRefs

Tags: angular, click, ngfor, custom-component, viewchild

From a custom component I have an ElementRef array to display images attached to received data in an *ngFor loop. Once the click event happens, all images display in one data card, and the other *ngFor data cards display with no images.

I started with parent components, then now customComponent, but same result. Console shows me that each ElementRef correctly has a distinct image, but only first one bundles all the images together, while the remaining cards are data-only. No images.

```
  @ViewChildren('clickBrag') bragwphoto: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.bragwphoto.changes.subscribe(() => {
        let array = this.bragwphoto.toArray();
        for (const a of array )
        {
          a.nativeElement.click();
        }
      });
    }
```

```
<bragwphoto *ngFor="let brag of brags; let index = index"

                      [name]="brag.name"
                      [date]="brag.updatedAt"
                      [post]="brag.post"
                      [fileID]="brag.fileID"
                      [length]="brag.comments.length"
                      >

                      <div *ngIf="brag.fileID" #clickBrag (click)="getBinary(brag.bragPhoto.data.data)"> </div>

                </bragwphoto>
```

Expected:

```
<customComponent>image, post,date...</customComponent>
<customComponent>image, post,date...</customComponent>
<customComponent>image, post,date...</customComponent>
etc...
```

```
Actual output is:
```

```
<customComponent>image,image,image, post,date...</customComponent>
<customComponent>post,date...</customComponent>
<customComponent>post,date...</customComponent>
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted.
The Problem: getElementsById will focus on the first element matching your query, and dump all photos there. 
So instead, reset the id of that first element and then appendChild your first image.
Immediately, the next call for getElementsById will bring a fresh element and it goes through the same process, looping until your array is exhausted.
Voila, all images will be in their proper place.

```
enter code here


ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.bragwphoto.changes.subscribe(() => {
        setTimeout(async () => {
       let bragPhotoButtons = this.clicker.toArray();
            for(var i = 0; i<bragPhotoButtons.length; i++) {
              bragPhotoButtons[i].nativeElement.click();
          }
        })
      })
    }

async getBinary(base64String: string, elem: any) {

      let photoSlot = 0;
        let img = new Image();
          img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + this.arrayBuffer2Base64(base64String);
            const ringaID = await elem.ringaID;

            const src = document.getElementById("bragPhotoDiv");
            // let src = document.getElementById("bragPhotoDiv").setAttribute("id", photoSlot + "modified" + ringaID);

          src.id = photoSlot + "modified" + ringaID;
        photoSlot++;

      src.appendChild(img);
  }
```